# Multi pin anotation show all default popup on then pin : iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

[image: map view]

I have multi pin available, now i want show all popoup(Callout) default without any tap it is possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [mapView selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES]; at the time of - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views

Comment: @MitsB :- Not working.

Comment: animation kadhi ne try mar..